# Print arrays with java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a Java program that prints arrays to methods. I am working on this code right now and I have gotten up to step 3 just fine. Step 3 is what I don't understand. I am not sure if I am just having a brain fart but I just do not understand what to do for this one step.

Here are the directions:

1.) Start a program in a class named `ArrayPrinter`. Ignore the main method for a moment.

2.) In your class, create a static method named `printArray` with one parameter of type `int[]` named `arr`. Inside this method, do the following.

a. Keep all of your output on one line using `System.out.print()` until directed to use `println()`.

b. Display an opening square bracket character.

c. Loop through the array that was passed into the method. Display the values in the array. Add a comma and a space after every value except for the last one.

d. Using `System.out.println()`, display a closing square bracket character.

3. In your main method, create the following array. Pass the reference to this array to the `printArray` method, run your program and verify that it works as expected.

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayPrinter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray(int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};)

}
public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
       int size = arr.length;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if(i<size-1){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the semi-colon `;`  that you've inserted when calling the `printArry`. Also that's not how to pass an anonymous array, it should be `printArray(new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8})`

Comment: @Aominè That still won't work as you can't define a variable when passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @JacobG. it should work ^^.

Comment: voting to close for typo.

Comment: That's why I disagree that OP made a typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
printArray(int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};)
```

You can't define a variable when using it as a parameter; to fix it, you can simply pass an anonymous variable:

```
printArray(new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8});
```

You can even change the `ArrayPrinter#printArray` method to take a variable amount of arguments so you can pass in elements directly:

```
public static void printArray(int... arr) {
    ...
}

printArray(5, 6, 7, 8);
```